# create a session using local storage in react js

Tags: reactjs

i am using local storage to set up a session in react js

`localStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);`// in login page set token in localstorage

in class componet if token exist show the data

```
componentDidMount() {
   const config = {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
     },
   };
  
   axios
     .get(
       "url" ,
       config
     )
```

in Funtional  componet if token exist show the data

```
useEffect(() => {
   const config = {
     headers: {
       Authorization: `token ` + localStorage.getItem("token"),
     },
   };


   axios
     .get(
       "url", 
       config  
     )
     .then((res) => {
       console.log(res.data.Diet);
```

i want if the local storage to act as session variable  and if local storage is empty re-direct to login page and say "login first"

Comment: any one help pls

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the item exists in the local storage and redirect if not like so :

```
   if (localStorage.getItem("token") === null) {
  //your redirection code here 
}
```

Comment: Any update, did you manage to reach your goal ?